# How use @import inside <style scoped> Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3

here I have a problem. in nuxt 2 I can use @import inside the  tag, but not in nuxt 3?

does anyone know how i should make it work in nuxt 3?

I was expecting like this.

```
...
<style scoped>
@import url('assets/css/custom.select2.css');
...
</style>
```

and what do I need to install and what setup should I do?.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you tried `<style scoped src="./style.css"></style>`  ?

Comment: Pretty I already saw this question on SO already.

Comment: @AnoopD  I've tried, it can but without using scoped

Comment: @kissu Yes that's right. the discussion for the nuxt 3 problem is still minimal.

Comment: @AlauddinAfifCassandra  The exact code i wrote  is working perfectly for me . Have a look https://stackblitz.com/github/nuxt/starter/tree/v3-stackblitz?file=assets/css/header.css

Comment: @AnoopD sorry, there's only app.vue there. and there is no style tag at all there.

Comment: @AlauddinAfifCassandra Sorry i shared it before forking .  Please have a look now https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-h97ucc?file=assets/css/header.css

Comment: @AnoopD I don't know why, components are nested too deep or something else doesn't seem to work. what is clear with your simple example it works

Comment: @AlauddinAfifCassandra Yea that was why i was wondering why it was not working for you .